# How to change the color of the modified (dirty) editor dot in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, color-scheme

I mean this white dot when a file has unsaved changes:

[image: Dot]

I couldn't find anything fitting [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color), only the border colors. Is it editable in the first place?

Comment: different themes have different colors, maybe it is in the light/dark/high contrast template

Comment: @rioV8 that's unrelated to my question

Comment: yes it is, that dot has different colors for different themes, so it is themable, but if it does not have a published theme name it is part of the theme template you have to start with when defining a theme

Comment: Well yeah, everything is themable, but I'm asking about the dot specifically. And just tab's foreground looks to be the closes answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the color of the dirty icon.  I saw it requested in this issue (but no work done on that part): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26284

For now, it is controlled by the `tab.activeForeground` ThemeColor.

Comment: Too bad, thanks for finding the issue.